# mod_rewrite sub-domain to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all requests for `http://blog.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/blog`

What I have below works except that all requests for `example.com` are also now going to `www.example.com/blog`.  Though, requests such as `example.com/about` are properly redirected to `www.example.com/about`.

What do I need to do to keep `example.com` from redirecting to `example.com/blog`?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog\.)?example\.com$ 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Because `(blog\.)?` means with or without `blog.`.